# Django migrations -- how do I wipe a model as part of a migration?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

I have a workflow where a model is generated by a script from some data also stored in the database:

```
SourceData -> management command generates -> Results
```

When I change how that Results model is generated, like adding a new field, I don't want to set a default value or update the existing models, I want to delete all of them and just run the script again to regenerate them with the new field:

```
Delete all Results -> run management command v2 -> Results (+ new field)
```

Is there an easy way to do this? All I've found online is how to accomplish this by deleting the *whole* database, which isn't what I want, I just want to drop this one table and recreate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't figure out *The Right Way* to do it, but managed to hack it by:

- Start with a clean git history (no dirty files) -- makes the next steps easier
- Rename the model in question to something else, like Model2
- Run makemigrations
- Revert all changes except the generated migration
- Reorder the generated migration file so `DeleteModel` comes before `CreateModel`, and change the name of the model being created in `CreateModel` back to the original model name. It should look like this:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("<app name>", "<previous migration>"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name="ModelName",
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="ModelName",
            fields=[
                # < all fields of your model >
            ],
            options={
                # < all meta options of your model >
            },
        ),
    ]
```